# How to synchronize UITableView scroll with keyboard animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I've got a table in which some of the cells contain input views (UITextField). The UITableView is normally constrained to the bottom of the screen using an NSLayoutConstraint with a constant of zero. When the keyboard appears, I set the constant to the keyboard height so the keyboard doesn't overlap the table. Then if the cell that the user tapped in is no longer visible (usually because it was near the bottom of the screen when they tapped on it) I scroll that cell back into view (tableView.scrollToRowAt).

All of these operations take place within an animation block.

Ultimately everything works as desired except for the fact that the scroll animation doesn't happen in sync with the other animations. So the end effect is that when the user taps the row, first the keyboard appears and covers that row, and then a moment later the row scrolls back into view.

Is there any way I can get all three animations to occur simultaneously?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Can you show your relevant code for handling the keyboard appearing and scrolling the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing around with textfield delegate methods.

Here is a list of those might be helpful:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

When user taps, it is going to call `shouldBeginEditing` and then show keyboard. You might want to scroll it exactly at this moment, so that when the keyboard animates in, the cell is probably already in place.

To implement you have to make your ViewController conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`, and then in `viewDidLoad()` you just set the delegate `yourTextField.delegate = self`

Comment: Do you mean shouldBeginEditing?

Comment: @Flarosa YES, sorry for the confusion!